# Java API Source Code

Tags: java, api

Where can I find the source code of the Java API?

Comment: Have you checked Google?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256988/the-very-basics-for-using-guava

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OpenJDK code: [Browse here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/awt/AWTUtilities.java.html)
For example, if you looking for AWTUtilities.java, go here in the above link:

```
src› share› classes› com› sun› awt› AWTUtilities.java
```

2. [OpenJDK project homepage](http://openjdk.java.net/) where they have all the instructions of downloading and building it
3. OpenJDK Mercurial Repo hosted [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/2d/jdk)
4. JDK Documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/)

Answer (score 19):

Install the JDK.  The sources for the public classes are packaged in src.zip.

Comment: I already found the code on Google Code Search, but out of curiosity is this only true for OpenJDK? I'm running Ubuntu and can't find it in the sun-java6-jdk directory.

Comment: Ubuntu repackages everything.  Have you installed sun-java6-source?

Comment: It is true with the JDK 7 directly from Oracle as well.  +1 for being by far the most correct answer here, and saving me decaminutes of time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean, but here is the [API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

Source for [OpenJDK implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6)

Answer (score 3):

You can also find them online at **http://www.docjar.org/**.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you mean the core libraries?

http://openjdk.java.net/groups/core-libs/

You might this alternative useful too:

http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to look up some classes, the following page is also a good source:

http://grepcode.com

It works for different versions of various libraries.