# How do you create a two dimensional collection?

Tags: java

Is there a simple way to create a 2-d collection?

Comment: Please improve the question by being more specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please tell me how to be specific I will edit it

Comment: Related (maybe even duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151775/how-can-i-make-a-map-with-two-indexes

Answer (score 2):

A two-dimensional collection is essentially having lists within a list. For example, to create a 2D ArrayList of strings, you would do something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

To add a new row, you would simply add a new ArrayList:

```
stringList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

And here's how to add an element to the first row:

```
stringList.get(0).add("example string");
```

Comment: But how would you add string ints and other data types

Comment: @Zingoflife: Why would you want to?  That doesn't sound very type safe to me.  Usually, when one uses a collection, one has an idea about what objects should go into it.  Tell us more about the problem you want to solve.  As it stands, your question is too broad for any answer to be helpful for a particular problem.

Comment: @scottb Agreed, also it's impossible to use int with ArrayLists because it is a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

A 2d collection is a bit abstract... what do you mean?
A double entry array is a 2d collection.

Why don't you use Multimaps from Guava library?
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained
,
Those collections ads everything that the jdk is missing for dealing with 2d collections.