# How do I add Guava to my Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, dependencies, guava

How do I add Guava to my Eclipse project? [UseGuavaInYourBuild](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild) gives directions for Maven, Gradle, Ivy, Buildr, and manual dependencies. I don't know how to use those build systems though. Do I need to convert my project or install additional software? I have added other libraries like Apache Commons and Mockito through manual dependencies (Eclipse menu –> Preferences... –> Java –> Build Path –> User Libraries). Google says that, "You can also just manually download JARs for the classes, sources and javadocs." But [the latest release (version 24.0)](https://github.com/google/guava/releases) doesn't offer JAR files to download. I found [a related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648911/how-to-add-guava-to-eclipse-project), but the answers seem to be out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just download the jar from one of the many sites that index Maven repositories, e.g. [**mvnrepository.com**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/24.0-jre).

[image: download from mvnrepository.com]

Or you could clone the [**Guava Github project**](https://github.com/google/guava) and build from source.

But I'd suggest you familiarize yourself with a build system of your choice (probably either Maven or Gradle, [here are](https://technologyconversations.com/2014/06/18/build-tools/) [some articles](https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-vs-maven) [to help](http://www.baeldung.com/ant-maven-gradle) [you decide](https://www.softwareyoga.com/10-reasons-why-we-chose-maven-over-gradle/)). It's 2018, no one works without a build system. IDEs are flakey. Reproducible builds are a must for proper software development. And dependency management is the sugar icing on top.