# Guava NoClassDefFoundErroron Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, guava

I'm trying to use Guava without Maven on Eclipse. I downloaded the JAR file from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.google.guava) and then followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4648947/11392406). However, when I try to run
`Set<Set<Card>> combos = Sets.combinations(ImmutableSet.copyOf(board),3);`
where board is an array of objects, I get this exception
`Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet`

My imports are

`import java.util.Set; import com.google.common.collect.*;`

I get the same error for any other classes from Guava.

My current package looks like this
[image: Package explorer]

What am I missing?

Comment: are you using gauva-gwt jar if not please remove it ,as per my understanding at runtime this jar is referenced by the jvm

Comment: @Raushan Kumar I removed it. It made no difference.

Comment: could you please update question with class and imports

Comment: @Raushan Kumar Updated. Do I need to do this step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649143/11392406? If yes, where do I find the repository?

Comment: Or is it the problem that the Source attachment is empty https://imgur.com/5SdLbM4?

Comment: please try to use direct import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet also check if this class is available in jar or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240726/discussion-between-raushan-kumar-and-dimitrismel).

Answer (score 0):

After starting a new project and doing the same process, it worked.